# UIPageViewController Implementation - Black Screen After Changing View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Trying to successfully implement an app that allows users to scroll between `UIViewControllers` using a UIPageViewController.

Currently, after swiping to the second `UIViewController`, the screen goes black and I cannot scroll anymore. Any ideas?

Here is my subclassed UIPageViewController code:

```
class ApplicationViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var registrationController : UIViewController!
var loginController : UIViewController!
var captureController : UIViewController!
var visibleVCS = [UIViewController]()
var index = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initControllers()
    reset()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func initControllers()
{
    registrationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegistrationViewController") as UIViewController
    loginController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
    captureController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CaptureViewController") as UIViewController

    visibleVCS = [registrationController, loginController, captureController]
}

func reset() {
    var currentController = viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
self.setViewControllers([currentController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if(index >= visibleVCS.count - 1){
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(++index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if(index <= 0){
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(--index)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController? {
    return visibleVCS[index];
}
}
```

Comment: you got any error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saving index as property in UIPageViewController din't work for me as well. To solve this I had to create a base UIViewController with index property as follow:

```
class PageItemController: UIViewController {

var index = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Then make all your pages subclasses of PageItemController and set their indexes corresponding to their position in array

```
func initControllers(){
    registrationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegistrationViewController") as PageItemController
    registrationController.index = 0
    loginController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as PageItemController
    loginController.index = 1
    captureController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CaptureViewController") as PageItemController
    captureController.index = 2
    // visibleVCS type must be [PageItemCotroller]
    visibleVCS = [registrationController, loginController, captureController]
}
```

And finally implement before and after methods based on currentController index

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.index > 0 {

        return visibleVCS[itemController.index - 1]

    }

    return nil

}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.index < visibleVCS.count - 1 {


        return visibleVCS[itemController.index + 1]
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i'll check this out shortly.

Comment: @Naxin Have you check it? Whats the result ?

Comment: I did try it, I believe the issue was indeed as a result of the index's from other tests I have done. I haven't been able to get it working using this solution yet due to crashes though, although I think this is storyboard related issues. Still debugging and will accept this solution if this is the case!

Comment: For what kind of crashes are you talking about ? As for storyboard try launching each VC separately from UIPageViewController and check if any of it is showing black screen

Comment: Thanks for the help Zellb, really appreciate it! I've chosen your answer but implemented as per my answer below (inspired from your use of indexing).

Answer (score 2):

@Zellb's answer did solve this issue. However this is the code I ended up using, which I find more manageable:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = indexOfViewController(viewController)!
    if (index != -1)
    {
        index++
        if (index >= visibleVCS.count)
        {
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            return visibleVCS[index]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = indexOfViewController(viewController)!
    if (index != -1)
    {
        index--
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            return visibleVCS[index]
        }
    }
    return nil

}

func indexOfViewController(viewController : UIViewController) -> Int?
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= visibleVCS.count; i++)
    {
        if (viewController == visibleVCS[i])
        {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Where visibleVC's is just an array of UIViewControllers as in my original code.